# Rg.Plugins.Popup error Rg.Plugins.Popup.Exceptions.RGPopupStackInvalidException: 'No Page in PopupStack'

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

i ran into this exception in my Xamarin Forms app that seems clear yet hard to resolve.
I created a kind of loader using the **Rg.Plugins.Popup** and i want to dismiss this loader when a user presses the back button while a web services is still running. But it throws this exception **Rg.Plugins.Popup.Exceptions.RGPopupStackInvalidException: 'No Page in PopupStack'** which means i am trying to remove a page that doesn't exist, and the app crashes. I have also followed the setup i saw [here](https://github.com/rotorgames/Rg.Plugins.Popup/wiki/Getting-started) in the Docs. Below is my code;

```
private async void RemovePage()
{
   var popPage = Rg.Plugins.Popup.Services.PopupNavigation.Instance.PopupStack;

   if (!popPage.Any() || popPage.Count == 0 || popPage == null)
   {
       return;
   }
   else
   {
       var lastPage = popPage.Last();

       if (lastPage.GetType() == typeof(LoadingPopup))
       {
           await Rg.Plugins.Popup.Services.PopupNavigation.Instance.RemovePageAsync(lastPage);
       }
       else
       {
          return;
       }
   }
}
```

Note: I am using the latest stable version 2.0.0.12 of Rg.Plugins.Popup and Xamarin.Forms 5.0.0.2012. Please what am i doing wrong here?

Comment: I haven't used this, but perhaps the back button tries to remove the page also. The setup link you give also has a later section that shows overriding `OnBackPressed`. Is that where you are calling this method from? If not, how are you calling it? (And in that case, can you re-work code so that it is done as part of OnBackPressed?)

Comment: Thank you so much @ToolmakerSteve for your quick response. I tried that as well, yet it throws the same error. However, i have a work around that has been working for me but i don't know the implications in performance wise.

In my trial, i had to add a new popup page to the stack after removing the desired one just to make sure the stack doesn't look empty.

Comment: Glad you found a work-around. FWIW: Reading the plugin docs, you shouldn't have to pop it yourself. So I still think that you only have the problem because you are explicitly popping it, AND the plugins normal logic is ALSO popping it. Why did you add code to pop it? Was it not going away? Have you tried what doc suggests: `public override void OnBackPressed() { Rg.Plugins.Popup.Popup.SendBackPressed(base.OnBackPressed); }`?

Comment: @PatNadis would u mind sharing ur work around am having the same issue but dont no what is causing it it did say same line as u Rg.Plugins.Popup.Exceptions.RGPopupStackInvalidException: 'No Page in PopupStack'

Comment: Okay I will check and get back to you ASAP @csharpdude77 so sorry for the late reply