# Issue with popup No Page in PopupStack rg popups

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

I found the cause of my previous error and issue its actually a popup I had forgotten about on the bind event of my code behind. I am using rg popups here.

https://github.com/rotorgames/Rg.Plugins.Popup

Here I am using the IsBusyPage

private IPopupNavigation _popup { get; set; }

```
public WeightLiftingPage()
{
  InitializeComponent();
  _popup = PopupNavigation.Instance;
}
```

This gets called on page load each time

```
public async void BindWeightLiftingsGird()
{ 
   var page = new IsBusyControl();
   await PopupNavigation.Instance.PushAsync(page);
 }
```

I came across this post [Rg.Plugins.Popup error Rg.Plugins.Popup.Exceptions.RGPopupStackInvalidException: 'No Page in PopupStack'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68497424/rg-plugins-popup-error-rg-plugins-popup-exceptions-rgpopupstackinvalidexception) But the author did not share their workaround.

The exact error i get is

> Rg.Plugins.Popup.Exceptions.RGPopupStackInvalidException: 'No Page in
> PopupStack'

Comment: What line is causing the exception?  This exception gets thrown when you attempt too Pop a page and the nav stack is empty, but none of the snippets of code you have shared is Popping, just pushing.

Comment: On my test, the code `PopupNavigation.Instance.PushAsync` would not throw that error. Could you provide more details for us to reproduce?